# Using include from a different folder

Tags: php, web

i have a project using php; i have an include folder where i have my header.php and footer.php
my style sheet and others are linked in the head tag of the header.php

i have another folder named calculator, now i include the header.php and footer.php in the index file of the calculator folder and it works but the css does not take effect

Here is the code in the calculator index file

```
<?php
    include '../include/header.php';
?>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name of Share</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Number of Shares</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Purchase Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>


    <?php
    include '../include/footer.php';
    ?>
```

please advise

Comment: Take a look at `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Your path for the css file ( you declare it in the header.php right?) isn't correct.

Comment: Use a slash `/` in your styles' href `<link href="/css/styles.css"..>`. This will always load from the (document)-root of your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my experience best way to include js and css files like this.

ex: 
Let's think that the css is inside asset and the path to asset is like `localhost\PROJECT\asset\css\style.css`

What is suggest is create a global variable as:

```
$path = 'http://localhost/PROJECT/';
```

And inside your header file where you set style sheet would be like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo  $path; ?>asset/css/style.css" >
```

Comment: Thanks @menaka but adding / to the css link didn't work